# MySQL JDBC plugin loading

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I've seen this type of code quite a bit in code which initializes the MySQL JDBC connection.

```
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://10.0.0.2:3306", "username", "password");
```

Now my question is why/when is this first line required? I've been able to connect without any problems to a MySQL database by just having this:

```
conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://10.0.0.2:3306", "username", "password");
```

I'm using Java 7 with the Connector/J 5.0.8 driver.

I don't have any import or class loading statements in my code which would directly load the MySQL driver, only the generic Java SQL interface classes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Short answer** : With JDBC drivers prior 4.0 (JDBC 4.0 introduce auto-loading of JDBC driver class)

> In previous versions of JDBC, to obtain a connection, you first had to
>   initialize your JDBC driver by calling the method Class.forName. This
>   methods required an object of type java.sql.Driver. Each JDBC driver
>   contains one or more classes that implements the interface
>   java.sql.Driver. The drivers for Java DB are
>   org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver and
>   org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver, and the one for MySQL Connector/J
>   is com.mysql.jdbc.Driver. See the documentation of your DBMS driver to
>   obtain the name of the class that implements the interface
>   java.sql.Driver.
>
> Any JDBC 4.0 drivers that are found in your class path are
>   automatically loaded. **(However, you must manually load any drivers
>   prior to JDBC 4.0 with the method Class.forName.)**

Source: [JDBC Basics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/connecting.html)